# tree view from json in ui-select

Tags: json, angularjs, ui-select

Looking to display a nested json in a treeview structure in ui-select.
I can create a tree using an angular directive:

**Code**

```
data:        
$scope.treeFamily = {
            name : "Parent",
            children: [{
                name : "Child1",
                children: [{
                    name : "Grandchild1",
                    children: []
                },{
                    name : "Grandchild2",
                    children: []
                },{
                    name : "Grandchild3",
                    children: []
                }]
            }, {
                name: "Child2",
                children: []
            }]
        };


directive:
        module.directive("tree", function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                transclude: true,
                scope: {family: '='},
                template:       
                    '<ul>' + 
                        '<li ng-transclude></li>' +
                        '<p>{{ family.name }}</p>' + 
                        '<li ng-repeat="child in family.children">' +
                            '<tree family="child"></tree>' +
                        '</li>' +
                    '</ul>',
                compile: function(tElement, tAttr, transclude) {
                    var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
                    var compiledContents;
                    return function(scope, iElement, iAttr) {
                        if(!compiledContents) {
                            compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude);
                        }
                        compiledContents(scope, function(clone, scope) {
                                 iElement.append(clone); 
                        });
                    };
                }
            };
        });

html:
        <tree family="treeFamily">

        </tree>
```

I would like to be able to search/select each node in ui-select.  Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, there really isn't any way of making your directive work inside of the ui-select directive as it is handling all of its options creation using repeats and does not give you the option of overriding this without in essence rewriting the ui-select box.  However, you can template the display items. start by flattening your data into an array:

```
 [{name: 'Parent', treelevel: 0},
  {name: 'Child', treelevel: 1},
  {name: 'Grandchild', treelevel: 2}]
```

then from there, write your ui-select as follows:

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
    <div style="padding-left: {{15 * person.treelevel}}px" ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

that will display everything in a tree like format. the following plunk has a working version of this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Rzlu6zIHOYzVlhQebh7V?p=preview